# numpy - updating doubly sliced marix not updating origin matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I'm having a problem with numpy matrixes.
given a matrix A and a list of indexes L, I'm trying to set A[i,j] = 1 for every i, j in the indexes list

I have the following code section:

```
 A = np.array([
[0,0,0,0,0,0],

[0,0,1,0,0,0],

[0,1,0,1,1,0],

[0,0,1,0,0,0],

[0,0,1,0,0,1],

[0,0,0,0,1,0]])
 x=(A[2,:])
 indexes = np.where(x==1)[0]
 A[indexes,:][:,indexes] = 1
*** print(A[indexes,:][:,indexes])
 print(A)
```

line *** does not update the values in the original A, while if I replace it with a single slice (  A[indexes,:]=1) id does change A

can someone care to explain the difference between the two and how should I work around it?

Comment: `A[indexes,:]` is a copy, not a view.

Answer (score 0):

The indexes is a simple array:

```
In [25]: indexes
Out[25]: array([1, 3, 4], dtype=int64)
```

With double indexing:

```
In [26]: A[indexes,:][:,indexes]
Out[26]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]])
```

This can't be used for set because `A[index,:]` is `copy`, not a `view`.

You can select the same elements using `ix_`.

```
In [28]: A[np.ix_(indexes,indexes)]
Out[28]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]])
```

Using that to set the elements:

```
In [29]: A[np.ix_(indexes,indexes)]=2
```

And checking:

```
In [30]: A[indexes,:][:,indexes]
Out[30]: 
array([[2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2]])

In [31]: A
Out[31]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 0],
       [0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]])
```

Doing the same thing as `ix_`:

```
In [32]: A[indexes[:,None],indexes]
Out[32]: 
array([[2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2]])
```

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html